# How to deploy to specific Firebase hosting service via CI? Getting "Too many arguments" error

Tags: firebase, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment, firebase-cli

I'm attempting to setup a CI for build and deployment of my website through GitLab. My website is hosted on Firebase.

I've setup a subdomain for testing so it doesn't interfere with the production site.

I'm able to use the command `firebase deploy --only hosting:test --message "Release: $PACKAGE_VERSION"` on my local machine with no issue.

When I change it to `firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --only hosting:test --message "Release: $PACKAGE_VERSION"` it gives me a `Too many arguments` error when running through the CI.

How can I get this to work?

Firebase-tools in my dev dependencies is at v6.6.0

Error message:

```
> firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --only hosting:test --message 'Version: $npm_package_version'


Error: Too many arguments. Run firebase help deploy for usage instructions
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! admiralfeb-net@2019.3.1 deploy-test: `firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --only hosting:test --message 'Version: $npm_package_version'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the admiralfeb-net@2019.3.1 deploy-test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-18T03_06_22_853Z-debug.log
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test --watch=true",
    "test-ci": "ng test --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox",
    "e2e-ci": "ng e2e --protractor-config=e2e/protractor-ci.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "deploy-test": "firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --only hosting:test --message 'Version: $npm_package_version'",
    "deploy-prod": "firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --only hosting:prod --message 'Version: $npm_package_version'"
  },
```

My gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - install
  - build
  - deploy-test
  - deploy-prod

install-dependencies:
  stage: install
  cache:
    policy: push
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm install --quiet
  only:
    changes:
      - package.json

build:
  stage: build
  cache:
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm run build-prod
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - dist/

deploy-test:
  stage: deploy-test
  environment: 
    name: test
    url: $FIREBASE_URL_TEST
  when: manual
  dependencies:
    - build
  cache:
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm run deploy-test

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy-prod
  environment: 
    name: production
    url: $FIREBASE_URL_PROD
  only: 
   - master
  when: manual
  dependencies:
    - build
  cache:
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm run deploy-prod
```

My firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": [{
    "target": "prod",
    "public": "dist/admiralfeb-net",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "target": "test",
    "public": "dist/admiralfeb-net",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

and my .firebaserc

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "admiralfebnet"
  },
  "targets": {
    "admiralfebnet": {
      "hosting": {
        "test": [
          "test-admiralfeb"
        ],
        "prod": [
          "admiralfebnet"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the variable `FIREBASE_TOKEN` is defined?

Comment: Yes, I've verified that it's still present in Gitlab's CI/CD variables. It starts with `1/`

Comment: I'm having this problem too! Never had it before though.

Comment: I noticed that I can deploy it normally using the same command and token locally, in my computer. I think this has something to do with the Gitlab runner

Answer (score 4):

After fighting with this for a day or two, I figured out what was incorrect.

In gitlab, there's a protected option for your env variables. This will hide them from pipelines not running on a protected tag or branch. I had this option checked.

Unchecked the protected option and reran the pipeline. I also removed the --token variable from the deploy call. Firebase will use the token if it's in the environment and called `FIREBASE_TOKEN`.